# Symfony2 twig extension get caller template

Tags: symfony, twig

Does anyone know a way to get the template (or its name) that called the Twig extension?

Comment: To display in twig? You could use the referrer var and pass it through to twig if that's what you mean?

Comment: What I need is, in the Twig extension, to know what template called the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the referrer into the twig template...

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('DefaultBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('referrer', $request->getRequestUri()));
    }

}
```

Comment: What I need is, in the Twig extension, to know what template called the extension.

Comment: I want to get the blocks that are defined in the template that calls the twig extension.